# RadioSelect widget with generic UpdateView

Tags: django

which is updated by `UpdateView`. And I wanted to add radio select to this. All solutions I have found with are `forms.py`, but since I use UpdateView I won't use `widget` in forms. Any ideas?

views.py

```
class AddPersonView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView)
    model = Trip
    template_name = 'tripplanner/add_new_member.html'
    fields = ["members"]
    success_url = '/'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        detailView = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user in detailView.members.all() or self.request.user in detailView.owners.all():
            return True
        return False
```

.html

```
{% extends "tripplanner/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{% trans "New member" %}</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What is `detailView = self.get_object()` doing here?

Comment: Furthermore you can perfectly specify a form in an `UpdateView`, this is likely the most elegant solution.

Comment: Isn't `members` a m2m by the way? A radiowidget typically is used to allow to select (at most) one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All solutions I have found with are `forms.py`, but since I use `UpdateView` I won't use widget in forms.

Well the one does not exclude the other at all. In fact, it is very common to specify the form class in a `CreateView`s and `UpdateView`s. Even if you do not specify a `Form` yourself, behind the curtains your `UpdateView` will construct one for you with default elements. Indeed, in the [**`ModelFormMixin`** class [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L70), we see:

> ```
> class ModelFormMixin(FormMixin, SingleObjectMixin):
>
>     # ...
>
>     def get_form_class(self):
>         # ...
>         return model_forms.modelform_factory(model, fields=self.fields)
> ```

so behind the curtains, it uses a `modelform_factory` to construct a `ModelForm` for you with the `fields` you provided. But nothing is stopping you from specifying your own form, and using that form.

In `forms.py`, you can thus specify in your `AddPersonForm` that you want to use a [**`RadioSelect`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect), although since `members` is likely a many-to-many relation, a [**`CheckboxSelectMultiple`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple) is more appropriate:

```
# app/forms.py

from app.models import Trip
from django import forms, RadioSelect

class AddPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ['members']
        widgets = {
            'members': RadioSelect()
        }
```

In your views, you can then make use of your `AddPersonForm`:

```
# app/views.py

from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from app.models import Trip
from app.forms import AddPersonForm

class AddPersonView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView)
    model = Trip
    template_name = 'tripplanner/add_new_member.html'
    form_class = AddPersonForm
    success_url = '/'

    # ...

    def test_func(self):
        detailView = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        return user in detailView.members.all() or user in detailView.owners.all()
```